# Disable/hide `Add Another Answer` button while inline-editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, inline-editor

It happened already more than once to me, that I accidentally clicked on the `Add Another Answer` button when I wanted to save my edit:

[image: Add Another Answer]

I assume this is because in the "normal edit" the `Save Edit` button was just the last grey box at the bottom, and now it is the second to last.

What do you think about hiding the `Add Another Answer` button while editing? It would make sense from a usability point of view. Or is it just something I (we) have to get used to?

Comment: When you are editing somebody else's question, you see both the text fields to edit the question, and to add your answer in the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not really sure about this suggestion, having just implemented it, I have to say I totally agree with it.

It simplifies things.

Comment: to be deployed today

Comment: my pleasure :) it was good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me a few times as well.  I catch myself before losing any work, but it's annoying.

I don't think disabling the button is the correct solution.  I do think re-coloring it or moving it to a different location might help.